# How can I copy the innerHTML of a section in HTML and create an exact copy of it as its child?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently try to mess around with JS and I wanted to be able to add a new section with onclick for (Set: , Rep: , Weight: ) but I keep running into the problem where the new created element is multiplying as the parent is getting larger everytime it it clicked. Is there a way I could fix this? [codepen](https://codepen.io/cmontg01/pen/vYejqbd)

```
<h1 class="h1 text-center">Log a Workout</h1>
<section class="workoutForm">
    <form action="">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Name of Workout:</label>
                <input type="text" id="workoutName">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="date">Date of Workout</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="date">Name of Exercise</label>
                <input type="text" id="exerciseName" placeholder="Ex: Barbell Bench Press">
                <ul>
                    <li id="entireSet">
                        <label for="exerciseName"> Set:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="set" id="set" required minlength="1">
                        <label for="exerciseName"> Reps:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="rep" id="rep" required minlength="1">
                        <label for="exerciseName"> Weight (lbs):</label>
                        <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" required minlength="1">
                        <input type="button" value="Add Set" onclick="addNewSet()">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input type="button" value="Add Exercise">
            </li>
            <li class="button">
                <button type="submit">Save Workout</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</section>

<script>
    function addNewSet() {
        const parent = document.getElementById("entireSet");
        const newSection = document.createElement("li");
        newSection.id = "newSet";
        newSection.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML;
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement("input");
        deleteBtn.type = "button";
        deleteBtn.value = "Delete";
        deleteBtn.id = "remove";
        newSection.appendChild(deleteBtn);
        parent.appendChild(newSection);
        deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() { //used to delete sets that were added
            newSection.remove();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow,
You are appending li element into li so when you were adding new set by using "entireSet" section then old 2 elements were getting added again.

by using `insertAfter` function new element will get added as sibling to "entireSet"

```js
function addNewSet() {
            const parent = document.getElementById("entireSet");
            const newSection = document.createElement("li");
            newSection.id = "newSet";
            newSection.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML;
            const deleteBtn = document.createElement("input");
            deleteBtn.type = "button";
            deleteBtn.value = "Delete";
            deleteBtn.id = "remove";
            newSection.appendChild(deleteBtn);
            insertAfter(newSection, parent);
            deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() { //used to delete sets that were added
                newSection.remove();
            });
        }
        
        function insertAfter(newNode, existingNode) {
            existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="h1 text-center">Log a Workout</h1>
    <section class="workoutForm">
        <form action="">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Name of Workout:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="workoutName">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="date">Date of Workout</label>
                    <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="date">Name of Exercise</label>
                    <input type="text" id="exerciseName" placeholder="Ex: Barbell Bench Press">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="entireSet">
                            <label for="exerciseName"> Set:</label>
                            <input type="number" name="set" id="set" required minlength="1">
                            <label for="exerciseName"> Reps:</label>
                            <input type="number" name="rep" id="rep" required minlength="1">
                            <label for="exerciseName"> Weight (lbs):</label>
                            <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" required minlength="1">
                            <input type="button" value="Add Set" onclick="addNewSet()">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="button" value="Add Exercise">
                </li>
                <li class="button">
                    <button type="submit">Save Workout</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```